# Terminology: Proper way to denote typical European 3-phase AC grid

Tags: ac, power-engineering, terminology, power-grid

The widely known 3-phase grid in Europe with 50 Hz and 400 V between two phases and 230 V between each phase and neutral is often referred to as "3 x 400 V" or "3 x 230 V".

Is one of these expressions "more true" or more precise than the other? Or does it depend on additional details, such as whether a neutral is used or not?

Or is there another, better way to denote it?

**[Edit, 19 Feb 2024] Context:**
Assume I was to write a technical data sheet for an electrical device that is plugged into the 3-phase grid and has a 3P + N + PE connector.

Comment: "Better" in what context? Electricians and electrical engineers may use different terms perhaps.

Comment: I agree with @Lundin - context is needed to be precise.

Comment: It depends on what you are used to in your counry. It's 3-phase so usually you only say the phase voltage, which is 400V. It will be 400V even without neutral as well. Googling reveals it's 400V that is provided to households, so 230V is not even mentioned, or it is listed as 400V/230V. What do you find used in your country?

Comment: High voltage engineers usually refers to line-line voltage.

Comment: @Lundin: Thanks! I was hoping that there was a universal way of doing it. Maybe a norm or something that defines the physical specs of this 3-phase grid, plus unambiguous terminology. But you're right, of course. Context is always important. I added some.

Comment: Called as 3N400

Comment: @Dave Electricians who work with this practically every day have a typical jargon and terms that are quite specific to their trade/to building installations - it is also quite possible that different terms are used in different European countries (I have no idea). Which in turn is not necessarily the same terms used by the EE who designed the equipment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to 'IEC 60038' courtesy [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60038#:%7E:text=Three%2Dphase%2050%20Hz,-230%20V%20%2F%20400&text=Suppliers%20using%20220%20V%20%2F%20380,least%20within%20the%20European%20Union.),

'Where two voltages are given separated by "/", the first is the root-mean-square voltage between a phase and the neutral connector, whereas the second is the corresponding root-mean-square voltage between two phases.'

Thus '3-phase 50 Hz 230 V / 400 V' refers to phase-to-neutral voltage of 230 V and phase-to-phase voltage of 400 V.